# Setting value to a copy of a slice of a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am setting up the following example which is similar to my situation and data:

Say, I have the following DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame ({'ID' : [1,2,3,4],
             'price' : [25,30,34,40],
             'Category' : ['small', 'medium','medium','small']})
```

```
  Category  ID  price
0    small   1     25
1   medium   2     30
2   medium   3     34
3    small   4     40
```

Now, I have the following function, which returns the discount amount based on the following logic:

```
def mapper(price, category):
    if category == 'small':
        discount = 0.1 * price
    else:
        discount = 0.2 * price
    return discount
```

Now I want the resulting DataFrame:

```
  Category  ID  price Discount
0    small   1     25      0.25
1   medium   2     30      0.6
2   medium   3     40      0.8
3    small   4     40      0.4
```

So I decided to call series.map on the column price because I don't want to use apply. I am working on a large DataFrame and map is much faster than apply.

I tried doing this:

```
for c in list(sample.Category.unique()):
    sample[sample['Category'] == c]['Discount'] = sample[sample['Category'] == c]['price'].map(lambda x: mapper(x,c))
```

And that didn't work as I expected because I am trying to set a value on a copy of a slice of the DataFrame.

My question is,
Is there a way to do this without using  `df.apply()`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One approach with [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) -

```
mask = df.Category.values=='small'
df['Discount'] = np.where(mask,df.price*0.01, df.price*0.02)
```

Another way to put things a bit differently -

```
df['Discount'] = df.price*0.01
df['Discount'][df.Category.values!='small'] *= 2
```

For performance, you might want to work with array data, so we could use `df.price.values` instead at places where `df.price` was used.

### Benchmarking

Approaches -

```
def app1(df): # Proposed app#1 here
    mask = df.Category.values=='small'
    df_price = df.price.values
    df['Discount'] = np.where(mask,df_price*0.01, df_price*0.02)
    return df

def app2(df): # Proposed app#2 here
    df['Discount'] = df.price.values*0.01
    df['Discount'][df.Category.values!='small'] *= 2
    return df

def app3(df): # @piRSquared's soln
    df.assign(
    Discount=((1 - (df.Category.values == 'small')) + 1) / 100 * df.price.values)
    return df

def app4(df): # @MaxU's soln
    df.assign(Discount=df.price * df.Category.map({'small':0.01}).fillna(0.02))
    return df
```

Timings -

1) Large dataset :

```
In [122]: df
Out[122]: 
  Category  ID  price  Discount
0    small   1     25      0.25
1   medium   2     30      0.60
2   medium   3     34      0.68
3    small   4     40      0.40

In [123]: df1 = pd.concat([df]*1000,axis=0)
     ...: df2 = pd.concat([df]*1000,axis=0)
     ...: df3 = pd.concat([df]*1000,axis=0)
     ...: df4 = pd.concat([df]*1000,axis=0)
     ...: 

In [124]: %timeit app1(df1)
     ...: %timeit app2(df2)
     ...: %timeit app3(df3)
     ...: %timeit app4(df4)
     ...: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 209 µs per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 63.2 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 351 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 720 µs per loop
```

2) Very large dataset :

```
In [125]: df1 = pd.concat([df]*10000,axis=0)
     ...: df2 = pd.concat([df]*10000,axis=0)
     ...: df3 = pd.concat([df]*10000,axis=0)
     ...: df4 = pd.concat([df]*10000,axis=0)
     ...: 

In [126]: %timeit app1(df1)
     ...: %timeit app2(df2)
     ...: %timeit app3(df3)
     ...: %timeit app4(df4)
     ...: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 758 µs per loop
1 loops, best of 3: 2.78 s per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.37 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 2.57 ms per loop
```

**Further boost with data reuse -**

```
def app1_modified(df):
    mask = df.Category.values=='small'
    df_price = df.price.values*0.01
    df['Discount'] = np.where(mask,df_price, df_price*2)
    return df
```

Timings -

```
In [133]: df1 = pd.concat([df]*10000,axis=0)
     ...: df2 = pd.concat([df]*10000,axis=0)
     ...: df3 = pd.concat([df]*10000,axis=0)
     ...: df4 = pd.concat([df]*10000,axis=0)
     ...: 

In [134]: %timeit app1(df1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 699 µs per loop

In [135]: %timeit app1_modified(df1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 655 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 4):

Also using some `numpy`

```
df.assign(
    Discount=((1 - (df.Category.values == 'small')) + 1) / 100 * df.price.values)

  Category  ID  price  Discount
0    small   1     25      0.25
1   medium   2     30      0.60
2   medium   3     34      0.68
3    small   4     40      0.40
```

---

The operative component being

```
(1 - (df.Category.values == 'small')) + 1) / 100 * df.price.values
```

This generates a single boolean array and performs simple arithmetic on it in order to get `.01` and `.02`.

---

***naive time testing over given data***

[image]

---

Thx @Divakar for pointing this out
For those using python 2.x, you'll need to force the float issue by using this.

```
df.assign(
    Discount=((1 - (df.Category.values == 'small')) + 1) / 100. * df.price.values)
```

Comment: I needed 100.0 or 1.0 for conversion to float values on my Python 2.x.

Comment: @Divakar nice comment.  Good for the 2.x ers.

Comment: Don't know much about pandas and got curious - Is `df.assign` more performant than `df['column_name']=`?

Comment: @Divakar no.  `pd.DataFrame.assign` is handy in that it produces a copy of `df` with the new columns specified in the keyword arguments.  It's nice for benchmarking as it doesn't clobber the original.  Also nice for pipe lining.  I used it in your example so that we had apples to apples comparison without having to recreate the `df` every iteration.

Answer (score 4):

Here is yet another Pandas approach:

```
In [67]: df.assign(Discount=df.price * df.Category.map({'small':0.01}).fillna(0.02))
Out[67]:
  Category  ID  price  Discount
0    small   1     25      0.25
1   medium   2     30      0.60
2   medium   3     34      0.68
3    small   4     40      0.40
```